# How can I use the value of the slider widget?

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider

I want to use the matplotlib slider widget to let the user choose a value. I want to add a button which the user can click on once they are done. This button simply closes the matplotlib window. Then I want to write a code that will use the slider value just before the window is closed.
I came up with the following script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button

#Create a slider
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axg = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)
gstart = 0
gend = 100
valinit = 50
valstep = 1
sg = Slider(axg, 'g', gstart, gend, valinit=valinit, valstep=valstep)

def update(event):
    pass

sg.on_changed(update)

#Create quit button
quitax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
quit_button = Button(quitax, 'Quit', color=axcolor, hovercolor='0.975')

def quit(event):
    plt.close()

quit_button.on_clicked(quit)

while True:
    if len(plt.get_fignums()) == 0:
        break

#Here I planned to add code using the slider position before the user 
#clicked on the quit button
g = sg.val
```

I hoped that the 'while loop' at the bottom will suspend the execution of the program until the matplotlib window is closed. Then, once it is closed, the execution will continue and I will be able to use the slider value for my purposes. Unfortunately, this does not work. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: your code works fine for me if I replace your `while` loop with `plt.show()`. This call is blocking, and will wait for the window to be closed, then the rest of the code executes.

Comment: @Diziet: Thank you, but I have tried that. With the replacement that you suggest, the value of g after the execution of the script is 50 (the initial value) regardless of the position of the slider before clicking on 'Quit'.

Comment: weird, that works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your code behaves differently on my system than on yours, but a possible solution is to store the updated value of the slider in a global variable:

```
slider_value = valinit

def update(val):
    global slider_value
    slider_value = val

sg.on_changed(update)
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that I have run this code originally in Spyder (Anaconda). I have re-run the code with the "while" loop replaced by `plt.show()` as #Diziet suggested above in PyCharm. Works perfectly as expected. So this must be an issue of environments or some wrong settings in my Spyder.
I should have tested this before posting the question, and apologize for dragging the community's attention in vain. Rookie's mistakes.